# Asymptotic relationship

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Consider functions f(n) = n^2 and g(n) = (1 + (-1)^n)n^2. What is the asymptotic relationsip (f is big-theta(g), f is big-omega(g) or f is big-O(g)) between the two functions?

I have graphed the g(n). It fluctuates between 0 and 2n^2. It does seem to satisfy c1g(n) ≤ |f(n)| ≤ c2g(n), but it does not quite satisfy for all n > n0. Because only at the points (not an interval), g(n) is greater than or smaller than f(n). Is there no asymptotic relationship between f(n) and g(n) because it cannot satisfy the condition "for all n > n0"?

Comment: Well, you should be able to see that there exists a constant $C$ and an $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $f(n)\ge C g(n)$ for all $n > n_0$ (make sure you can show this!). Which asymptotic relationship has this definition?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. If you want to produce beautiful and beautifully formatted mathematical texts, please consider using [Math Jax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).